# Arba'a Umeya - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows one hundred four?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to go through 104 chapters of Tehillim before you find the first instance of the word Halleluyah.

(Berachos 9b)

Comment: "I've made it through 104 chapters of Psalms.  Hallelujah!"

Comment: "Alex hit 10k points.  Hallelujah!"

Comment: Thanks! Though like they say, no one remembers the second man on the moon...

Comment: @Alex: Well, Buzz Aldrin has the advantage of a distinctive name. They guy who really gets the short end of the stick is Michael Collins.

Answer (score 2):

Sedom = 104

Midyan = 104

Monoach = 104

Nochum = 104

4 x the name of Hashem = 104

Answer (score 2):

104 are the *dapim* in *Eruvin*.